# Some part of infoWindow outside of map?

Tags: google-maps

When the page has loaded and the map is visible, an infoWindow opens on the map without any click. But sometimes, depending on the markers position, part of infoWindows is outside of map. Is there a way to prevent this from happen and always get infoWindow within the map?

*Update*

The problem is that the infowindow is shows before the markers appears on the map. So the infowindow starts att the markers position, but when the marker are in place the infowindow jumps up a little bit so that it starts just above the marker. But since the first position was before the marker, the infowindow get outside the map.

Anyone who knows why the infowindows shows on the map first, despite that the placing of the markers are first in the code? Is it possible to check if all markers are in place before activate the infowindow?

Comment: If you are not able to post a link, please post the javascript that you are using the create the info window.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a link to the page with the issue?

In [Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions), by default, the map will pan to ensure an infoWindow is fully visible (this is behaviour that you can disable in the infoWindowOption *disableAutoPan*):

> By default, the info window will pan
>   the map so that it is fully visible
>   when it opens.

The problem you are seeing might be related to the timing of the infoWindow.open call.  Having access to the page will help us diagnose the issue.